# WPF: TreeView does not show any children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I've been trying to get my first `TreeView` to work, at first without the *ViewModel*. But no matter what I do, it doesn't show any children, even though the binding is correct.

I'm using two `Item` templates, one for hierarchical and another for data. You can see the important parts for both below:

```
class GrupoTag
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public GrupoTag Pai { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> ListaFilhos { get; set; }
    public List<GrupoTag> SubGrupos { get; set; }
    public GrupoTag(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        ListaFilhos = new List<Tag>();
        SubGrupos = new List<GrupoTag>();
    }
    public List<object> Filhos
    {
        get
        {
            List<object> lista = new List<object>();
            foreach (GrupoTag subGrupo in SubGrupos)
                lista.Add(subGrupo);
            foreach (Tag filho in ListaFilhos)
                lista.Add(filho);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Tag
    {
        public GrupoTag Pai { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Tag(string nome)
        {
            Nome = nome;
        }
        public Tag(GrupoTag pai, string nome)
        {
            Pai = pai;
            Nome = nome;
        }
    }
```

The XAML binding to all of this:

```
<TreeView Name="MenuTags">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="xml2Excel2:GrupoTag" ItemsSource="{Binding Filhos}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="xml2Excel2:Tag">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

But the property "Filhos" on the `GrupoTag` class is never accessed. I've tried putting a breakpoint in there, throwing an exception, but it's simply never called. And the `TreeView` only displays the names of the collection of `GrupoTag`s I assigned to it as its `ItemSource` in code-behind.

```
MenuTags.ItemsSource = arvoreTeste.SubGrupos;
```

I've read all the related questions and corrected the code for the respective errors, but I'm still lost here.

EDIT 1: So I modified the code of the classes to conform to the simple interface below:

```
class ITag
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ITag> Filhos { get; set; }
}
```

As per Benin comment, GrupoTag now uses a single property stored in a `ObservableCollection` to represent its children. And, as per Adnan answer removed the `DataType` from the XAML `TreeView`. Now it looks like this:

```
<TreeView Name="ArvoreTags">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

It works, the `TreeView`is functional. But I don't know why.

Comment: You'll want to use `ObservableCollection` so that updates to the items are reflected in the view.  Also, you want a simple property and do any manipulations at an appropriate area outside the property getter.  What you have here is generating a new list on every access to the `Filhos` property.  That's a binding nightmare.

Comment: I have tried switching the binding from `Filhos` to `SubGrupos` (some of the nodes have children of this type) and changing the type of all the properties to `ObservableCollection` and it still did nothing.

Comment: It doesn't matter where I point the binding to, it just doesn't show anything.  Pointing directly to one collection or the other, even when they are `ObservableCollection`, does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your TreeView ItemSource and DataType. And I would agree to Berins comment , you should avoid making new list to each access to Filhos property. TreeView works very good with Polymorphis, I mean with data types.

```
<TreeView   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            DataContext="{Binding ProjectNodes_DataContext}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProjectNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
```

My Property is:

```
private ProjectNodesVM mProjectNodes_DataContext;
public ProjectNodesVM ProjectNodes_DataContext
{
    get { return mProjectNodes_DataContext; }
    protected set
    {
        SetProperty(ref mProjectNodes_DataContext, value);
    }
}
```

and class ProjectNodesVM has:

```
public ObservableCollection<ProjectNode> Nodes {
    get { return mNodes; }
    protected set { SetProperty(ref mNodes, value); }
}
```

inside ProjectNode class i have:

```
private string mHeader;
public string Header
{
    get { return mHeader; }
    set { SetProperty(ref mHeader, value); }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with giving the `TreeView` a `ItemSource` or `DataType`? I gave these properties to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` already. Is it not where they supposed to be? I'm really confused, sorry.

Comment: @manoftheyear The tree needs an ItemsSource for the root items. The HierarchicalDataTemplate needs one for child items. Neither one needs a DataType.

Comment: Tried removing the `DataType`s and creating an interface and it worked with a modified XAML. I just don't know why. I will edit the question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you need DataType. TreeViews works with DataTypes, ListViews works with ItemSources.

Comment: @AdnanPoljak That doesn't even make sense. DataType in that context does nothing. It has nothing to do with ItemsSource in any case.

Comment: I only needed the ItemsSource on the treeview and did not need a DataType as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer to my specific case, not yours it seems

> The children must be a "property".

So:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Tag> ListaFilhos ; //doesn't work
 public ObservableCollection<Tag> ListaFilhos {get; set;} //works
```